# не работает redirect Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

На новой версии всё работает. На старой отказывается.
Закинул в контроллер фрагмент `return back()->with('status', 'Profile updated!');`
В blade прописал получение:

```
@if (session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ dd(session('status')) }}
    </div>
@endif
```

После нажатия на клавишу - нет того, чего хотелось бы увидеть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контроллер работает 100% - его суть обработать данные - добавив новые записи в бд, а после выполнения сделать редирект с возвращением этой записи и выводом её в blade

Answer (score 0):

`return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'Profile updated!');`

Comment: Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1489996/edit)».